# Remove one value from a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to all rows that only contain zeros from a NumPy array. For example, I want to remove `[0,0]` from

```
n = np.array([[1,2], [0,0], [5,6]])
```

and be left with:

```
np.array([[1,2], [5,6]])
```

Comment: you want to remove a row based on its value or its index?

Comment: @user1220022: What kind of values do you want to test?  any sequence?  or only know whether there are only zeroes in the row?

Comment: whether there are only zeros in the row

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove the second row from a numpy table:

```
import numpy
n = numpy.array([[1,2],[0,0],[5,6]])
new_n = numpy.delete(n, 1, axis=0)
```

To remove rows containing only 0:

```
import numpy
n = numpy.array([[1,2],[0,0],[5,6]])
idxs = numpy.any(n != 0, axis=1) # index of rows with at least one non zero value
n_non_zero = n[idxs, :] # selection of the wanted rows
```

Comment: `numpy.delete(n, numpy.s_[1], axis=0)` can be simplified as `numpy.delete(n, 1)`.  Furthermore, `numpy.any(n != 0, axis=1)` can be simplified as `n.any(axis=1)`.  And `n[idx,:]` can simply be replaced by `n[idx]`.

Comment: PS: Sorry, `numpy.delete(n, numpy.s_[1], axis=0)` does need an axis parameter: it can be simplified as `numpy.delete(n, 1, axis=0)`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete any row that only contains zeros, the fastest way I can think of is:

```
n = numpy.array([[1,2], [0,0], [5,6]])

keep_row = n.any(axis=1)  # Index of rows with at least one non-zero value
n_non_zero = n[keep_row]  # Rows to keep, only
```

This runs much faster than Simon's answer, because `n.any()` stops checking the values of each row as soon as it encounters any non-zero value (in Simon's answer, all the elements of each row are compared to zero first, which results in unnecessary computations).

---

Here is a generalization of the answer, if you ever need to remove a rows that have a specific value (instead of removing only rows that only contain zeros):

```
n = numpy.array([[1,2], [0,0], [5,6]])

to_be_removed = [0, 0]  # Can be any row values: [5, 6], etc.
other_rows = (n != to_be_removed).any(axis=1)  # Rows that have at least one element that differs
n_other_rows = n[other_rows]  # New array with rows equal to to_be_removed removed.
```

Note that this solution is not fully optimized: even if the first element of `to_be_removed` does not match, the remaining row elements from `n` are compared to those of `to_be_removed` (as in Simon's answer).

I'd be curious to know if there is a simple efficient NumPy solution to the more general problem of deleting rows with a specific value.

Using [cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html) loops might be a fast solution: for each row, element comparison could be stopped as soon as one element from the row differs from the corresponding element in `to_be_removed`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to remove specific rows or columns.

For example:

```
n = [[1,2], [0,0], [5,6]]

np.delete(n, 1, axis=0)
```

The output will be:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: This deletes the second element right? I should of been more specific, I want to remove the element which is `[0,0]` and there will only be one of them.

Comment: This answer tries to delete by index, not what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

To delete according to value,which is an Object.
To do like this:

```
>>> n
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 0],
       [5, 6]])
>>> bl=n==[0,0]
>>> bl
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> bl=np.any(bl,axis=1)
>>> bl
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> ind=np.nonzero(bl)[0]
>>> ind
array([1])
>>> np.delete(n,ind,axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: +1 good suggestion, worked for me. You can also use `np.all()` instead to get those elements that are an *exact match* and not just contain a 0 (that is only [0,0]).